# Modify data in a modal window when loading it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-core

I have a presentation with user notes. The button processing works for me, a modal window appears. Now I need to set its title and body when downloading. I get the body from the parent class of the button, no problem with that.

Here is my code:

```js
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.card .btn-info'));

function heangleClick() {
  const parent = this.parentNode;
  console.log($(this).parent().find('.fullBody').html());
  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
  $('#exampleModalLongTitle').val('123'); // not work

};

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', heangleClick);
});
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="~/js/showTittleTodo.js"></script>
```

How can i set values ​​in js file exampleModalLongTitle and modalBody

Comment: try to first set the information and then display the modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try below which is not work.

```
$('#exampleModalLongTitle').val('123');// not work
```

Please replace below instead of that

```
$('#exampleModalLongTitle').text('123');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set html or text instead val.

```
$('#exampleModalLongTitle').html('123');
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this code:

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');    

$('#exampleModalCenter').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#exampleModalLongTitle').val('123');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your js as following, using `shown.bs.modal` event on modal element you can attach a callback which fires when the modal window is completely `shown`

```
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.card .btn-info'));

function heangleClick() {
  const parent = this.parentNode;
  console.log($(this).parent().find('.fullBody').html());
  $('#exampleModalCenter').one('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#exampleModalLongTitle').val('123');
  })
  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
};

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', heangleClick);
});
```